# How to repeat sequence: 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10 in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a list: 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10. I tried repeat function in r but no clue. Many thanks

Comment: The pattern is like c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,9,10,11,12,13,14)  , and it could be extendable. number 9 has to be added on the biggest front number  "8" by 1

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. You answered my question. many thanks.

Comment: Many thanks. It is my first time . I am trying to figure out how to click

Comment: Sorry,akrun. I am trying to make the pattern flexible. Like using variable to express. Like, repeat 3 times: 1,2,3,4,5,6,,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10? m=3, n=6,k=6+1, nt=4

Comment: It works well. I tried. But many thanks for your response

Comment: thanks for the comments. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** This inserts 1:10 into 1:10 after position 6 giving the requested sequence.  n=10 is the maximum number and k=6 is the maximum number before it repeats.  (For the example in the comment under the question use n=14 and k=8.)

```
n <- 10; k <- 6
append(1:n, 1:n, k)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  7  8  9 10
```

If you need to handle edge cases such as n=k=0 then write it using seq_len rather than using the colon operator like this:

```
append(seq_len(n), seq_len(n), k)
```

**2)** It could also be done explicitly like this:

```
c(1:k, 1:n, (k+1):n)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  7  8  9 10
```

If you need to handle edge cases such as n=k=0 then write it like this instead:

```
c(seq_len(k), seq_len(n), seq(to = n, length = n-k))
```

**3)** Another possibility is the following.  It handles edge cases too.

```
s <- seq_len(n)
c(head(s, k), s, tail(s, n-k))
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Many thanks. My final goal is to make it flexible with n to create pattern. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Grothenddieck, Many thanks. How to make it more flexible. Like, repeat 3 times:       
 1,2,3,4,5,6,,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10?

Comment: Like using variable to express. Like, repeat 3 times: 1,2,3,4,5,6,,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10? m=3, n=6,k=6+1, nt=4

Comment: Using s from (3) use this: c(rep(head(s, k), m), s, rep(tail(s, n-k), m)). where m is 2 or 3.  The other solutions could be similarly extended.

Comment: Hi Grothendieck. It works well. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Grothendieck. If I want to make it more flexible like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,11,12,13,14,15. there are 3 different length. 12346=6      7,8,9,10=5   11,12,13,14,15=5. How to modify the code? Many thanks.repeat m=2

Comment: Hi Grothendieck. If I want to make it more flexible like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,11,12,13,14,15. there are 3 different length. 12346=6      7,8,9,10=5   11,12,13,14,15=5. How to modify the code? Many thanks.repeat m=2. The added vector has to start with the previous maximum+1

Comment: First form s as the first 15 numbers and then take the first 6, the first 15-5, the last 15-6 and the last 5.  You should be able to do that yourself at this point if you study the answer.

Comment: HI Grothendieck. I have a new issue about this question. How to use a general code to create the sequence above? for example for I don't need to change manually for the different length :c(rep(head(s, k), m), s, rep(tail(s, n-k), m))-this is three, but how about 4, and 5,...n. I want to use a general expression, use a variable like L. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** An option is `sequence`

```
c(sequence(c(6, 10)), 7:10)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  7  8  9 10
```

**2)**( With updated sequence in the comments

```
c(sequence(c(8, 14)), 9:14)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

---

**3)** Or using `rep`

```
c(rep(1:6, 2), rep(7:10, 2))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  7  8  9 10
```

**4)**( Or simplified with a single `rep`

```
unlist(rep(list(1:6, 7:10), each = 2))
```

EDIT: Added the much needed numbering

Comment: Many thanks. How to make it flexible. For example, the number 7 is based on the "6" plus "1" . My goal is to make a list pattern by adding number.

Comment: Hi akrun. I have a new issue about this question. How to use a general code to create the sequence above? for example , I don't need to change manually for the different length :unlist(rep(list(1:6, 7:10), each = 2))- for exampl, unlist(rep(list(1:m, m+1:m+s, m+s+1: m+s+1,...., m+s+1+x: m+s+1+y), "..." means a variable "n" .? many thanks.